# Bash Scripting: Initialzing a path with a text file to a variable & iterating the list in the text file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm currently learning the basics of bash scripting (coming from a Pythonic background) and It seems I've run into an interesting situation in which I need a bit of explanation with.

My goal is to create a Path variable that contains a text file. I use an if-statement to check whether the file exists in the directory. If it exists, It will print "It exists".

Then I created a for-loop to print out the elements in the file list. When I execute the program, there is no output and no errors being thrown.

Any help or explanation would be much appreciated! Here is the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
veggieFile=/home/lynova/Potato/hewwo.txt 

if [ -e veggieFile ]; then 

    echo "File exists"

    for VEGGIE in $(cat veggieFile  ); do

        echo "Veggies are ${VEGGIE}"

    done

fi
```

Comment: Related: [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the file `veggieFile` exists, not the file whose name is stored in the variable `veggieFile`. You need to expand the name:

```
if [ -e "$veggieFile" ]; then
    echo "File exists"
    while IFS= read -r veggie; do
        echo "Veggies are $veggie"
    done < "$veggieFile"
fi
```

See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more information on why I used a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop. Also, all-caps names are reserved; use lower- or mixed-case names for your own variables.

---

A possible source of confusion might be in how quotes are used. In Python, `veggieFile` would be a variable whose value is used, while `"veggieFile"` is a literal string. In shell, though, *all* strings are literal strings; quotes are only used to escape the contained characters. For example, the quoted word `"foo bar"` is equivalent to the `foo\ bar`. You need to use `$` to get the value of a variable.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much for your insightful comment, particularly on the quotes - this explanation makes sense. I was able to execute the program successfully on my end!  I'll take a look at the BASH FAQ for further learning!